# Filter by keyword in clojure returning ClassCastException error

Tags: filter, clojure, classcastexception

I am defining my table as

```
(def persons '({:id 1 :name "olle"} {:id 2 :name "anna"} {:id 3 :name "isak"} {:id 4 :name "beatrice"}))
```

And then attempting to use the filter command with `(< :id 2)` being my function and `persons` being my argument that I'm filtering.

```
(filter (< :id 2) persons);
```

I am being returned this error and do not know how to fix my program

```
ClassCastException clojure.lang.Keyword cannot be cast to java.lang.Number  clojure.lang.Numbers.lt (Numbers.java:221)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the first argument to `filter` should be a predicate *function* but in your example it's just the *value* of `(< :id 2)`.

```
(filter #(< (:id %) 2) persons)
```

The function should take one argument (the current element) and return a value indicating whether it satisfies the predicate. This is also valid, longer syntax for the same thing:

```
(filter (fn [p] (< (:id p) 2)) persons)
```

You could also `defn` a standalone predicate function like this:

```
(defn id-less-than-2? [person]
  (< (:id person) 2))
(filter id-less-than-2? persons)
```